# Mapping URL in main menu to every page

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, url-mapping

I am using in my `grails 2.3.4` project with `spring security` and `spring securit ui`.

I am having scaffolde my domain `contact` to the view. I have also a `.gsp` page which is not scarfolded.

My links from my main menue looks like that:

```
<li><a href="pricing">Pricing</a></li>
<li><a href="contact/create">Contact</a></li>
```

Thats my `URLMappings`

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {

        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/private/$controller/$action?/$id?(.${format})?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view:"/index")
        "/pricing"(view:"/pricing")
        "/private/dashboard"(view:"/private/dashboard")
        "/contact/create"(view:"/contact/create")
        "500"(view:'/error')

    }
}
```

My problem is when I am using this two links from my mainpage `/` then everythings works fine. However using them from `5432:localhost/TestApp/pricing` I am getting the link `5432:localhost/TestApp/pricing/contact/create`
which goes is not available. If I am using `<li><a href="../contact/create">Contact</a></li>`, I am going to `5432:localhost/contact/create`, which is also not available. How to go to `contact/create` from every page?

I appreciate your reply!

Comment: Let Grails do the heavy lifting and use createLink.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Thx for your answer! The problem with `createLink` is that my style would be gone and has to be redesigned, which is now used for the `<a>` tag... Because of this reason I am using this complicated solution ;P

Comment: Your style? Not sure I follow. If you are saying you need a style attribute on the link the createLink will take that attribute as well.

Comment: Did you mean `<a href="/contact/create">Contact</a>` in the question? Note `/contact/..` in href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest and safest approach would be

```
<li><g:link uri="/contact/create">Contact</g:link></li>
```

Other attributes on the `g:link` tag will pass through to the generated `a` tag, with the exception of `id` - you need to use `elementId` instead, as `id` is treated as a parameter to the link generation (controller/action/id)

```
<li><g:link uri="/contact/create" class="nav" elementId="contactlink">Contact</g:link></li>
```

would become

```
<li><a href="/TestApp/contact/create" class="nav" id="contactlink">Contact</a></li>
```

(where `/TestApp` is the application context path - if you deploy the app at a different context path then then link will change to match).